# Using Dask to_datetime and Pandas date offsets

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a function which increments a yyyy-mm format date with an offset so that it begins at the first day of the following month. Previously I have used the Pandas pd.to_datetime and pd.offsets.MonthBegin functions to do this, however I am trying to apply this with Dask. To my knowledge, whilst Dask does have a to_datetime function it doesn't have an offsets function that will perform the same as Pandas. That being said, I tried combining the two approaches (using dd.to_datetime and pd.offsets.MonthBegin) and have observed the results that I want without any errors. My question is, is this approach recommended/reliable or is there a better way that will just use Dask functions?

Code that produces some examples is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client

# Setup cluster
client = Client()

# create test dataframe

test_dates = ["2019-01",
              "2019-02",
              "2019-03",
              "2019-04",
              "2019-05",
              "2019-06",
              "2019-07",
              "2019-08",
              "2019-09",
              "2019-10",
              "2019-11",
              "2019-12"]

df_a = pd.DataFrame(test_dates, columns=['test_month'])
ddf_a = dd.from_pandas(df_a, npartitions=4)

ddf_a["test_month_updated"] = (dd.to_datetime(ddf_a["test_month"].str[0:4] + ddf_a["test_month"].str[-2:] + '01') + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')

ddf_a.compute()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dask's map_partitions, which will map a function on each of the partitions, i.e. each pandas DataFrame. Ref docs: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions.html